# AngularJs Client side not connecting to server side

Tags: angularjs, nginx

The problem is client side is not able to connect to server side. The issue as for as I know it is sending Request Method `OPTIONS` instead of `GET`. Look at these headers

`General:`

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:9000
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/api/v1/gyms
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

`Response Headers:`

```
view source
Content-Length:26454
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

`Request Headers:`

```
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, accept-language, authorization, dev
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:9000
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/VTraining
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.71 Safari/537.36
X-FirePHP-Version:0.0.6
```

Isn't the General header should have `GET` Request Method. I deployed the client application on `nginx`.

This is my `nginx.conf` file `HTTP` settings.

```
http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
client_max_body_size 20m;
server {
      listen 9077;
      server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
      index index.html;
      root Web/Web/nginx/app/;

      add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
  add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE";
  add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "X-Filter-Query, Authorization";

   location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|html|woff|ttf|svg|eot|otf)$ {
      expires 1M;
      access_log off;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }

   location / {
      try_files $uri /index.html;
if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
                    add_header Content-Length 0;
                    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
                    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept';
                    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST';
                    return 200;
            }
  }    


}
```

Comment: Not of servers need special overrides to server OPTIONS responses by default.  Check nginx documentation maybe this quick search helps ? http://superuser.com/questions/636464/any-modules-to-handle-http-options-requests-in-nginx

Comment: what is the code that send this request? if you say the Method should be other then `OPTIONS` then you might want to check the code that initiate this request.

Comment: is it a Frame-Work you are using?

Comment: Orgin page is `localhost:80` ?  and request is to `localhost:9000` ?  So you need OPTIONS to work on the server (`localhost:9000`) for CORS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing can you make Origin and Target the same (like `localhost:80`) this will side-step the need for you to make OPTIONS work at `localhost:9000`.

Comment: @DarrylMiles How can I make Origin and Target same? Can you help me?

Comment: The webpage shown in the browser of the AngularJS application is `http://localhost/VTraining` so why are you trying to access a different webserver on port 9000 for the AJAX response (as `http://localhost:9000/api/v1/gyms`) ?  Can you remove the ":9000" part ?

Comment: @DarrylMiles The server side application is running on `localhost:9000` that is why I added this. I have also added my `nginx.conf` file. Please help me out.

Comment: @TomerW I am using Play frame work.

Comment: `server { listen 9077; }` are you sure this is the correct config ?  how many servers do you need to test with ?  can you not use a single server on a single port, this same server serves the angularjs pages and is also the server you are preforming AJAX too ?  then no need for HTTP method OPTIONS or CORS.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/api/v1/gyms. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.` Now This error is also appearing in console

Comment: Indeed this is CORS  and the only problem you have, please read up on it and how to setup nginx. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` check manually with `curl` or `wget` the exact headers you get.